# How to set Current Item in View Pager

Tags: java, android

I have `RecyclerView` and View Pager in my code and I'm trying to set `setCurrentItem` in view pager But it does not work, what should I do?

My Code :

```
pot = getIntent().getIntExtra("pot",0);

viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

slidAdapter = new SlidAdapter(this, userList);

viewPager.setAdapter(slidAdapter);

viewPager.setCurrentItem(pot);
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you did not add sufficient information:

To set the current item in `ViewPager`:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true)
```

Position must be an integer value.